# My variable is a number type, but CurrencyPipe still throws an Invalid argument exception

Tags: angular, typescript, currency-pipe

I checked the `typeof` the variable and it is a `number`. However, CurrencyPipe still throws the invalid argument exception.

`currencyPipe.transform(myNum, 'USD', true, '1.2-2');`

Does CurrencyPipe have other restrictions for input than type `number`?

Answer (score 0):

> Does CurrencyPipe have other restrictions for input than type number?

No. We can only assume that the check for `number` that you did is wrong.

Comment: I did 'typeof myNum' - is there another way?